# WPF: Filtering items in ItemsControl and ContentControl

Tags: wpf, filter, wpf-controls, itemscontrol, contentcontrol

I have created a UI user control that represents a calendar month view. The control is consisted of 42 borders arranged in 7x6 grid (7 days in a week x 6 weeks to show per month).

Next, I have created an `Appointment` class. It has a `DateTime AppointmentDate` property which should determine the border in my control in which the appointment would appear in.

I want to be able to provide a collection of appointments to my UI control and then the control should determine which border will contain the appointment items and which will remain empty.

What is the best way to achieve this? I was thinking of the following: To add an `ItemsControl` to each border in my control and then to bind each of those to the appointment collection. Then I would create and apply a filter to each of those ItemControls to show or omit related appointments. Is this smart, coding, memory and performance wise? Is there a better way to achieve this?

What if I want each border to hold only one appointment (There will be no appointments in the collection that have the same appointment date)? Should I replace `ItemsControl` with `ContentControl`? Is it possible to apply filtering to ContentControls and if yes, how?

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably take a different approach to the whole thing. I would create a Collection for the Days, and each Day would have an integer property for Date, Week, DayOfWeek, and a Collection for Appointments.

I would then create an ItemsControl which is bound to this Collection.

I would make the ItemsControl.PanelTemplate into a Grid with 7 columns and 6 rows, and the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate into a Border containing the Date and a ListBox or ItemsControl to hold the Appointments. I would setup the ItemsControl.ItemStyle so that Grid.Row and Grid.Column are bound to Week and DayOfWeek respectively.

Comment: Which control would you use to store appointments in a day if there can be only one appointment per day? `ListBox` is useful for a collection of day's appointments, but I am missing a container for single appointment object. Is `ContentControl` the one I am looking for?

Comment: Why would you need one or the other? A `ListBox` with one item should look the same as a `ContentControl` with one item in it as well. The only thing that might be distracting is the ListBox selection caret but you could use a PropertyTrigger and style that away when there is only one item in the list. But it also looks like you don't know if you need a list of appointments per day anyway. If you can only have one appointment per day, you should not use an ItemsControl (or derived class) anyway. Any ContentControl derived-class could be used in this case.

Comment: @Rachel: Would you spare your thoughts on the Days collection please? If my UI control would represent a month view of a calendar I assume that you didn't have in mind populating Days collection with 365 collection items per year. Thanks for helping me with this Rachel!

Comment: @Boris The Days collection would contain data for the currently viewed month. If the user switched Months, I'd load the next month's days and appointments. For a single appointment per day I would either style the ItemsTemplate of the ItemsControl however I wanted the appointment to look, or I would use a ContentControl with the Content bound to the Appointment, and then use a DataTemplate to define how the Appointment should be displayed.

Comment: @Rachel, awesome! It all seems much simpler now. Thank you.

Comment: @Rachel, just a quick question: In your answer, when you wrote "ItemsControl.ItemTemplate into a Border containing the Date and a ListBox or ItemsControl to hold the Appointments", by Date did you have dependency property in mind or a `TextBlock`?

Comment: @Boris I just meant a TextBlock holding the day's date

Answer (score 2):

I've mocked up a different approach than what you were suggesting. It's simplified and I've made an assumption or two, but let's give this a shot.

Instead of using a grid and matching days into the grid, let's use a WrapPanel and just put children into it that each represent a day.

In your App.xaml.cs you can put some code that will create a `Day` object.

```
public class Day
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        var daysCollection = new List<Day>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            daysCollection.Add(new Day
                {
                    // arbitrary sample data
                    Date = new DateTime(2011, 04, i),
                    Appointments =
                        new List<Appointment>
                            {
                                new Appointment
                                    {
                                        Date = new DateTime(2011, 04, i),
                                        Description = "Some descriptive text"
                                    }
                            }
                });
        }

        this.Properties.Add("DaysCollection", daysCollection );
    }
}
```

Now we have a collection of days. The appointments aren't important for this part of the sample.

Now, we create a simple calendar UserControl and bind it to a CalendarViewModel.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DaysCalendarBinding.Views.Calendar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="210" Width="210">
    <WrapPanel x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" 
               ItemHeight="30" ItemWidth="30" 
               Loaded="wrapPanel_Loaded">
    </WrapPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The ViewModel

```
public class CalendarViewModel
{
    public CalendarViewModel()
    {

    }

    public CalendarViewModel(IEnumerable<Day> inputDays)
    {
        // determine first day of the month passed in
        var firstDate =
            (from day in inputDays 
             orderby day.Date.Day 
             select day.Date).First();
        var todayIs = firstDate.DayOfWeek;
        var valueOfToday = (int) todayIs;

        // create this many blank day children
        DaysInMonth = new List<Day>();
        for (int i = valueOfToday; i > 0; i--)
        {
            // the start of some cheeze. I know. It's a sample.
            DaysInMonth.Add(new Day { Date = new DateTime(1,1,1) });
        }

        // add the rest ofthe days in to the collection
        foreach(var day in inputDays)
        {
            DaysInMonth.Add(day);
        }
    }

    public List<Day> DaysInMonth { get; private set; }
}
```

With an event handler for when the wrapPanel is loaded

```
private void wrapPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var day in ((CalendarViewModel)DataContext).DaysInMonth)
    {
        wrapPanel.Children.Add(
                 new DayView { 
                        DataContext = new DayViewModel(day) });
    }
}
```

Now, we create the DayViewModel and DayView control which we are creating and adding to the WrapPanel.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DaysCalendarBinding.Views.DayView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="30">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel Height="30" Width="30" Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock FontSize="7"  Text="{Binding DayDate}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border> </UserControl>
```

The ViewModel

```
public class DayViewModel
{
    private Day innerDay;

    public DayViewModel() {}

    public DayViewModel(Day day)
    {
        innerDay = day;
    }

    public string DayDate
    {
        get
        {
            // I know this is a cheesy approach. It's a sample. :)
            if (innerDay.Date.Year != 1)
                // this only intended to demonstrate some content
                return innerDay.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Remove(3) +
                       "   " + innerDay.Date.Day;
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Now finally, our mainwindow, where we add a calendar control, add a CalendarViewModel and hopefully, when we press F5, it shows up for you. :)

```
<Window x:Class="DaysCalendarBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:DaysCalendarBinding.Views" Title="Calendar Demo" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Views:Calendar x:Name="calendarControl"></Views:Calendar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);
    calendarControl.DataContext = 
                          new CalendarViewModel((IEnumerable<Day>)Application
                              .Current
                              .Properties["DaysCollection"]);
}
```

I may have made a mistake or two transposing this into here from my solution. But, I hope it conveys the idea.  What this ends up looking like for me is this.

March Calendar

[image: March Calendar Screenshot]

April Calendar

[image: April Calendar Screenshot]

Now, comes the part of putting this all together so that it works for you. This just demonstrates the technique.  Presenting a meaningful control shouldn't be that hard.

Cheers.

Comment: Awesome example, +1 from me too. In the end, I would prefer to avoid `WrapPanel` as a personal choice, but nevertheless this is such a good example. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To advise you on your first question I would direct you to the [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) and mention that

> When a user binds a WPF property to a
>   collection of data, WPF automatically
>   creates a view to wrap the collection,
>   and binds the property to the view,
>   not the raw collection. [Source](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387)

This should help you separate the concerns between your entire data set and the visible portion.

For your second question, once you have chosen filtering logic you can better model your control to work with it. Since I can't see your code and know little about what you're doing this is fairly generic. I would recommending binding a control to a single appointment (so it shows only one appointment, as you requested). If it is null or empty, show nothing on that date. That will allow you to manipulate the data (the Model) and not the control (the View) but still achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: if I implement `CollectionViewSource` for each of the lists that holds the appointments for a particular day and apply filtering on those, what would be the performance impact and memory footprint? Since there would be 42 lists targeting the collection view source which would be filtered 42 times, I am little concerned about the user experience. What do you think?